# Help with differential equation problem

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

Could someone give any directions on this problem:

A ball is thrown into upright direction. Acceleration $a$ satisfies the following equation:  $$a = -g$$

where $(g = 9.81 \frac{m}{s²}, a = s''(t))$. Solve the function for distance travelled $s = s(t)$, when at $t = 0$, the ball has initial velocity $v_o$ and initial height $s_o$

How should I start solving this? thnx for any help =)

Comment: Just integrate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are given that $a(t)=\frac{d^2s}{dt^2}=-g$ where $a(t)$ is the acceleration and $s(t)$ is the height of the particle at time $t$ with $v(0)=s'(0)=v_0$ and $s(0)=s_0$. Integrating the equation $s''(t)=-g$ with respect to $t$ twice and using the initial velocity and displacement you get $s(t)=-\frac{1}{2}gt^2+v_0t+s_0$ as the equation of motion.

Comment: you are welcome good luck.